# If an archer falls

Tags: dnd-3.5e

If an archer falls down do the arrows fall out of his quiver?  If not or if they do please explain why or why not.  Just a simple explanation would be great.

Comment: Can you give us some details about why you need to know? Are you asking as the player of an archer character, or as a DM? Are you asking about something that already happened and you're trying to figure out if the group handled it correctly, or about something that *might* happen?

Comment: If you don't explain *why this matters*, in terms of "what problem are you trying to solve?" then you can expect that there will be votes to close this question.  Please edit you question to include Why This Matters.

Answer (score 3):

RAW - No. The reason for this is that there are no rules in the manuales which state when an archer falls down that they fall out. The weapons, weapons description, and ammunition pages all fail to mention anything like this, so its assumed to not affect you.

Should arrows possibly fall out if an archer falls down? Yes, but remember that this is a world with magic. Maybe theres a light magnet which prevents them from falling out but not from being drawn.

Comment: Thank you.  Now I have to show this to my son.  He is the DM and thinks the rules should have this in them  So he has a house rule that you have to have a cap on the quiver or if you fall down they will spill out.   I love playing the game with my son and grandchildren and friends but some of his house rules are difficult.   Thank you again.